# Date subtraction

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to select all the users in our database that put their accounts on hold the day they created them. Users can only go on hold for 1 month, so the logic would be selecting users where....

```
day(hold_until - 1 month) = day(signup)
```

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: What does function `day()` do? Cast `hold_until` and `signup` to date? It is not a defined function in PostgreSQL. Wild guess: `(hold_until::date - interval '1 month') = signup::date`.

Comment: The table definition would be instrumental. Data type of said columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TheTable
 WHERE date(singup) = date(hold_until - INTERVAL '6 months')
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the RDBMS You're using, but assuming this is PostgreSQL, you can try this:

```
...where
day(hold_until - interval '1 month') = day(signup)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `timestamp` columns:

```
... WHERE (hold_until - interval '1 month')::date = singnup::date
```